Access joined table on field udpated event
Is it possible to access the joined table in a field updated event without having to add an additional query to get the joined record?
For instance, a graph that looks like this:
 public class MyGraph : PXGraph<MyGraph>
 {
     public PXSelectJoin<Detail, InnerJoin<Header, On<Detail.hdrId, Equal<Header.id>>>> MyView;

     public void _(Events.FieldUpdated<Detail.someField> e)
     {
         //TODO: find the Header record that is joined to the Detail record that fired this event?
         
         /*  Don't want the overhead of doing something like this:
         
         Detail dtl = (Detail)e.Row;
         
         Header hdr = PXSelect<Header, Where<Header.id, Equal<@P.AsInt>>>.Select(this,dtl.HdrId);
         if(hdr != null)
         {
             //more code here.
         }
        */
     }
 }

This is for 22 R1.
TIA!

No. The event is by cache type and doesn't know anything about your view specifically that I am aware of.
The PXSelect to header will go into query cache and will after first call just use the cached results so there should be very little overhead (even more so if selecting by keys).
